# Select a Slick slider 1.3.5 after page load so it has focus to navigate with arrow keys

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend

I want the slider to be selected automatically after the loading of page. Meaning that I want to be able to navigate through the slider using the arrow keys right after the page load, without clicking on it first.

This is the workign slider but I have to click on it first before the arrow keys work.

https://codepen.io/jinzagon/pen/YzqpdLj

HTML

```
<section class="top_slider">
    <div>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/288x288?text=1">
    </div>
    <div>
                   <img src="http://placehold.it/288x288?text=1">
    </div>
    <div>
                  <img src="http://placehold.it/288x288?text=1">
    </div>
    <div>
                 <img src="http://placehold.it/288x288?text=1">
    </div>
    <div>
               <img src="http://placehold.it/288x288?text=1">
    </div>
</section>
```

CSS

```
.slider {
  background-color: white;
  margin: 100px auto;
  height: auto!important;
}

.slick-slide {
  margin: 0px 20px;
}

.slick-slide img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

JS

```
$(".top_slider").slick({
    dots: true,
    infinite: true,
    centerMode: true,
    slidesToShow: 3,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. Put focus on the slider after it is loaded**

After the slider is initialised, you can put focus on the slider so that the keyboard can be used without tabbing to it or clicking on it first... but note that **you can only set focus on an element that can get focus** e.g. an `a`,  `button` or `input`. You're first slide contains a link so we can use it.

In Slick 1.3.9 or below (which you are using), you can use the `onInit` callback and select the link in the first div of the `.slide-track` like this:

```
$(".top_slider").slick({
    dots: true,
    infinite: false,
    centerMode: true,
    slidesToShow: 3,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    onInit: function() {
        $(".top_slider .slick-track div:first-of-type a").focus();
    },
});
```

In Slick 1.4.0 and above, you use the callback event *before* you initialise the slider, and you can select the first slide more easily using the `.slick-current` class (note, you still need to select a focus-able element in the slide):

```
/* Bind the event BEFORE initialising slick */
$('.top_slider').on('init', function(event, slick){
    $(".top_slider .slick-current a").focus();
});
/* Now you can initialise Slick */
$(".top_slider").slick({
    /*Settings....*/
});
```

**2. Automatically scroll to the slider when the page loads**

You just need the following line to make your page to scroll down to the slider when the page loads:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $('.top_slider').offset().top}, 500);
});
```

We get the position of the top of the slider using the `.top_slider` class and set `scrollTop` to this value in the `animate` function - this will animate the scroll to that location.

**Working Snippet** Putting this all together:

```js
$('.top_slider').on('init', function(event, slick) {
  $(".top_slider .slick-current a").focus();
});

$(".top_slider").slick({
  dots: true,
  infinite: false,
  centerMode: true,
  slidesToShow: 3,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  onInit: function() {
    $(".top_slider .slick-track div:first-of-type a").focus();
  },
});

  $('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: $('.top_slider' ).offset().top}, 500);
```

```css
.slider {
  background-color: white;
  margin: 100px auto;
  height: auto!important;
}

.slick-slide {
  margin: 0px 20px;
}

.slick-slide img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.3.15/slick.css">

<h1>HEADER HERE...</h1>
<h2>Some more content to scroll past...</h2>
<section class="top_slider">
  <div>
    <a href="google.com"><img src="http://placehold.it/288x288?text=1"></a>
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/288x288?text=1">
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/288x288?text=1">
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/288x288?text=1">
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/288x288?text=1">
  </div>
</section>
<p>Content to make the page long enough to see the scroll...</p>
<p>Content to make the page long enough to see the scroll...</p>
<p>Content to make the page long enough to see the scroll...</p>
<p>Content to make the page long enough to see the scroll...</p>
<p>Content to make the page long enough to see the scroll...</p>
<p>Content to make the page long enough to see the scroll...</p>
<p>Content to make the page long enough to see the scroll...</p>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.3.15/slick.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.Your example doesn't seem to work, or atleast the slider. Maybe you forgot the Slick script ?

Comment: Or i think I misspelled what I wanted. Normally when the page loads, you have to click on the slider to be able to navigate on it. I want to directly navigate on it without clicking on it first.

Comment: This code will jump to the slider when the page loads, which is the title of your question... is that not what you wanted? I didn’t include the slick script because it wasn’t needed to demonstrate the jump down the page.

Comment: I'm sorry again if I didn't express what I wanted. Your code does indeed the job by going to the slider, BUT, i can't navigate in the slider unless I click on it first. I don't want to click on it first, I want to navigate directly after the page loads.

Comment: @SeitoKimbo I’ve updated my answer in include autoplay, is that what you meant?

Comment: Here is a gif explaining everything. imgur.com/a/QEzGOUN It's not about autoplay. Note that i'm able to control the slider only if I clicked on it. I want to be able to control it without clicking on it first.

Comment: @SeitoKimbo OK, that image helped, I think I understand what you want now! You want to put *focus* on the slider so that the keys will work without first tabbing to or clicking on the slider - is that right? I've got that working - see my updated answer!

Comment: yes yes YES !! I'm so happy with the result. Thank you so much. Sorry if I didn't explain clearly my idea. Yes I think it was the focus. I tried putting "FocusOnSelect" as it was mentionned in the documentation but didn't work.

Comment: And while i'm on it,can I move the outlined element  on the active slide with every other slide ? So as I'm browsing between them I can press enter on each one of them.

Comment: Making it work with clicking enter, would need the behaviour of the slider itself to be changed. At the moment it works like that when you tab through the slides, rather than arrow through them - the arrows keys work just like the navigation dots. FYI, I've also taken a look at your other question - when I read it again it was different to this one, it was about getting returning focus after events. I've added an answer for that too!

Comment: I will just have to thank you immensely for your help. I will accept the answer in the other one too. Well I will see if I can manage to get the "enter" input working. If not, unfortunally I will be posting another post here. I'm still learning Javascript but I have a little project that requires all of that. Anyway thank you :)

Comment: @SeitoKimbo you could take a look focus on the `a` element in every action that can select a slide (e.g. tab, arrow key ec) by at binding an event to the keys, a bit like you do for the ESC key - not sure if it work work, but thats where I'd start! You would probably also need to do it when the navigation dots are selected too, and if you use autoplay. Might get complicated but if you do try it and get stuck, you can always ask here :) Good luck with it!